# How to convert pid to const char pointer in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert pid types to a const char pointer so that I can pass them in as an argument in a execlp function.

eg. `execlp("/bin/ps", "-f", "--ppid", "9340,9345,9346,9342");`

I know that you can convert a pid to a string eg. `const std::string my_pid(str_pid.str());`

And a string to a const char pointer eg. `my_pid.c_str();`

But how would you concatenate multiple pids into a const char pointer so I can run the execlp command with them?

Comment: What library are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

`ostringstream` is probably what you want.

For instance,

```
std::ostringstream ostr;
for (int i=0; i<pids.count(); i++)
{
    if (i > 0) ostr << ',';
    ostr << pids[i];
}

execlp("/bin/ps", "-f", "--ppid", ostr.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

A [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) would be a good C++ way to do it.

```
std::stringstream myStream;
myStream << "a c string" << aStringObject << std::endl; // operate on the stream
std::string myNewString = myStream.str(); // create a string object
```

Treating the data as a stream is a fairly generic way to allow you to serialize and deserialize custom or builtin types.  Custom types could include `operator<<` and `operator>>` to allow insertion and extraction respectively.

This approach also should have the advantage of speed over using temporary string objects and manipulating them.  The stingstream (or any of its base classes) will employ a buffer under the covers. A loop with temporary strings will invoke several more constructors/allocations/destructors each iteration.  This does depend on the underlying string representation as well. A copy on write ([COW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)) string implementation would have fewer allocations and may only update a reference, but updating the work string will still require a new string.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all of your values together into a single `std::string` first, the pass the final `std::string` value to `execlp()`, eg:

```
std::string pids;
for (however many pids you have)
{
    if (!pids.empty())
        pids += ",";
    pids += std::string(str_pid.str());
}

execlp("/bin/ps", "-f", "--ppid", pids.c_str());
```